# Commandline override the /Out paramter of a vcbuild task of msbuild

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way to specify the output like

```
msbuild zlibvc.sln /t:zlibvc  /p:OUT=$(OutDir)\zlib1.dll
```

by example, changing the output from the standard zlibwapi.dll to zlib1.dll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of C# projects, we do modify csproject file in the following two places like this:

**Before:**

```
<AssemblyName>zlibwapi.dll</AssemblyName>
```

and

```
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
```

**After:**

```
<ZLibAssemblyName Condition="$(ZLibAssemblyName) == '' ">zlibwapi.dll</ZLibAssemblyName>
<AssemblyName>$(ZLibAssemblyName)</AssemblyName>
```

and

```
<ZLibOutputPath Condition="$(ZLibOutputPath) == '' ">bin\</ZLibOutputPath>
<OutputPath>$(ZLibOutputPath)</OutputPath>
```

Then call your msbuild command like below:

```
msbuild zlibvc.sln /t:zlibvc  /p:ZLibOutputPath=$(OutDir)\ /p:ZLibAssemblyName=zlib1.dll
```

Hope this or a similar thing works in vcbuild task as well.

Comment: Wouldnt that make every assembly in the solution have that name? he needs to specify just the project to msbuild (instead of the sln) so that he can override the assembly name.

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden, Oh. I had the assumption of one project in this solution. The change I had done now may help then

Comment: Thanks, but ... without changing solution files from other sources. In an automated build environment you want to fetch that zlib and build it as-is. Also this approach isn't working on vcbuild environments (not CSharp). I've seen other "source-changing" solutions here with vsprops, but that again is not working with VS2008.

Comment: Even in automated build environments as well you can use this approach since most of them will support passing of property values in build triggers as far as I know. Or else you can wrap it up in an MSBuild file and call from the automation process. But, I am not sure why it is not working out in vcbuild enviroment because, as far as I know this approach should work similar way in vcbuild and CSharp.